# HTML5 drag upload in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I have setup an HTML5 drag and drop upload into my site.  The problem that I have is when a user is uploading a large file, they must wait for the upload to finish before navigating and using the rest of the site.

So, what I'd like to do is allow the user to drag files to the main site and then have it automatically open a new window and start the upload there so they can still use the rest of the site while the upload is happening.  Anyone have and advice on how to accomplish this or if it can even be done?

Comment: you might want to go back and accept some answers to your old questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to open the new window when the drop event occurs.  Below is a full example.

First, we have a file upload region and events that handle the drag and drop:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fileUpload" style="height:200; width:200; border:1px solid #ddd;"><span id="lbl">Drag and drop file here...</span></div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#fileUpload').get(0).addEventListener("drop", upload, false);        
    $('#fileUpload').get(0).addEventListener("dragenter", noopHandler, false);
    $('#fileUpload').get(0).addEventListener("dragexit", noopHandler, false);
    $('#fileUpload').get(0).addEventListener("dragover", noopHandler, false);

    function noopHandler(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    function upload(e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
       e.preventDefault();

       fileList = e.dataTransfer.files;
       var fileCount = fileList.length;

       // Only call the handler if 1 or more files was dropped.
       if (fileCount > 0) {
           window.open("upload.html");
       }
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the pop-up window (`upload.html`), we get the files from the parent window and begin the upload:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var fileList = window.opener.fileList;

        var reader = new FileReader();     
        reader.onloadend = function(e) { alert("Uploaded"); }

        for (file in fileList) {
            // Upload
            reader.readAsDataURL(fileList[file]);
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Give this a try and hopefully it helps solve the problem.

Comment: I'll try this.  I didn't know you could pass files through windows.  Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't able to try it out yet.  I'll be able to get into it in a couple days.  Been swamped with work lately.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is a single-page application, Web Workers might be a solution.